# An error occurred (IllegalLocationConstraintException) when calling the CreateBucket operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using the aws api I can create a bucket in us-east-1 but not other regions else, why is this ?

```
$ aws s3api create-bucket --bucket snap2web-12 --region us-east-1
{
    "Location": "/snap2web-12"
}
19:21:27 durrantm u2018 /home/durrantm/Dropbox/_/Michael/cli_scripts 
$ aws s3api create-bucket --bucket snap2web-13 --region us-east-2

An error occurred (IllegalLocationConstraintException) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The unspecified location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.
19:21:44 durrantm u2018 /home/durrantm/Dropbox/_/Michael/cli_scripts 
$ aws s3api create-bucket --bucket snap2web-14 --region us-west-1

An error occurred (IllegalLocationConstraintException) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The unspecified location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.
19:23:19 durrantm u2018 /home/durrantm/Dropbox/_/Michael/cli_scripts 
$
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [aws s3api create-bucket —bucket make exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49174673/aws-s3api-create-bucket-bucket-make-exception)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Two possible fixes:

Use the `s3` command:

```
aws s3 mb s3://snap2web-13 --region us-east-2
```

or, according to [the s3api examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/create-bucket.html#examples) (emphasis mine):

> **Regions outside of us-east-1 require the appropriate
>   LocationConstraint to be specified in order to create the bucket in
>   the desired region**:

```
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket snap2web-13 --region us-east-2 --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=us-east-2
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is confusing, but it is actually happening because the bucket name that you specified is not unique. Bucket names must be globally unique across AWS. Try using a different bucket name which is unlikely to exist. If the error persists, than it is something else.

Answer (score 0):

I had change bucket name too then It did works alright.

So very name and try again

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35776733)